# Trello : How to check if a authorized user has board permission using jquery

Tags: jquery, trello

I'm working on a project that utilizes [Trello API](https://trello.com/docs/api/index.html). I'm trying to check if a authorized user has board permissions by check response code on a GET request. The else statement works fine and authorized users can proceed, but non authorized users get a 401 response code but it isn't triggering the alert. Any help appreciated

```
Trello.boards.get('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', function(e){
if(e.status === 401){
  alert("No Auth"); 
} else {
  $('#login').hide(); // Hide Login
  $('#form').parent().show(); // Initiate Form   
}
```

Comment: Then are you sure that `e.status` is the right field and it's actually an integer value?

Answer (score 0):

`console.log(e.status)` under the condition that you expect it to be a 401. See what it logs. if it is undefined or null, console.log(e) and see what you're getting back.

Comment: console doesn't log, only the 401 response is shown in the console.